# Python Selenium randomly fails to find element

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

My script is doing the same thing for every car in a list, but at a random passage

```
vec = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                        expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((
                            'id', 'elp.jobDetailsVehicle.input.jobVehicleEngineCode'))).get_attribute('value')
```

fails to find the element and i get this error:

```
  File "script.py", line 79, in check_recall
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
  File "C:\Users\Be26.LANGWEDEL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0125FDC3+2555331]
    Ordinal0 [0x011F77F1+2127857]
    Ordinal0 [0x010F2E08+1060360]
    Ordinal0 [0x0111E49E+1238174]
    Ordinal0 [0x0111E69B+1238683]
    Ordinal0 [0x01149252+1413714]
    Ordinal0 [0x01137B54+1342292]
    Ordinal0 [0x011475FA+1406458]
    Ordinal0 [0x01137976+1341814]
    Ordinal0 [0x011136B6+1193654]
    Ordinal0 [0x01114546+1197382]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x013F9622+1619522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x014A882C+2336844]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012F23E1+541697]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012F1443+537699]
    Ordinal0 [0x011FD18E+2150798]
    Ordinal0 [0x01201518+2168088]
    Ordinal0 [0x01201660+2168416]
    Ordinal0 [0x0120B330+2208560]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76C3FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77057A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77057A6E+238]
```

I already tried conditions like `presence_of_element_located` - same error. It's completely random.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
This is the entire loop:

```
for line in lines:
    if line[3] == '.':
        license_plate = line[23:33]
        name = line[38:52]
        vin = line[88:105]
        if '-' in license_plate and 'VSSZZZ' in vin:
            driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element('id', 'mainFs'))

            entry_license_plate = driver.find_element('id', 'elp.searchVehicle.input.licensePlate')
            entry_license_plate.send_keys(license_plate)

            driver.find_element('id', 'vaws.vehsearch.btn.search').click()

            vec = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((
                    'id', 'elp.jobDetailsVehicle.input.jobVehicleEngineCode'))).get_attribute('value')

            WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(('id', 'vaws.sys.recall')))

            try:
                recall = driver.find_element('id', 'recall.info.state').get_attribute('src')
            except NoSuchElementException:
                recall = driver.find_element('id', 'recall.info.warning').get_attribute('src')

            if 'dummy.gif' in recall or 'info.gif' in recall:
                recall = 'Nein'
            elif 'warning.gif' in recall:
                recall = 'Ja'

            final_list += f'{name} | {license_plate} | {vin} | Motor-Kennbuchstabe: {vec} ' \
                          f'| Feldmaßnahme: {recall}\n'

            print('done')

            driver.switch_to.default_content()

            WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(('id', 'toolbar.button.new.job'))).click()
```

The page is a in-house site from our company, so i'm not allowed to show it.

Comment: We need to see all your code and a page you are working on in order to help you

Comment: The page is a in-house site from our company, so i'm not allowed to show it.

Comment: I understand. But in order to help we need to debug, to see more details.

Comment: I added the loop

Comment: I see, thanks. Possibly some previous step is not 100% stable, maybe the previous click not 100% working stable, need to debug this...

Answer (score 0):

This just means that the 60 second timeout ended without having observed what is in the `until` method.

Try to put this inside of a try :

```
try:
    vec = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                        expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((
                            'id', 'elp.jobDetailsVehicle.input.jobVehicleEngineCode'))).get_attribute('value')
except:
    print("Timeout")
```

Or, to try again until we got no error :

```
while True:
    try:
        vec = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                        expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((
                            'id', 'elp.jobDetailsVehicle.input.jobVehicleEngineCode'))).get_attribute('value')
        # break out of the loop if successful
        break
    except:
        # continue the loop if not successful
        continue
    print("Timeout")
```

Comment: But the element is definitive present and visible

Comment: Are you sure it does not change from time to time, for example due to a preventing web scraping strategy on the website ?

Comment: Yes, im sure it doesn't change. I checkt it 100 times...

Comment: Then I have no idea what is happening, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the problem: at the beginning I load the default profile with

```py
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")}\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'
```

Without that I don't have these random errors.
Does anyone know why?